# Upcast in Java Difference

Tags: java, casting

```
class A {
}

class B extends A {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        B b1 = new B();
        B b2 = new B();

        A a = b1;
        A c = (A) b2;
    }
}
```

Is there any difference between `a` and `c`? `b1` is directly referenced and `b2` is upcasted to `A` and then referenced to `c` of type `A`.

Comment: The cast is superfluous. There's no difference.

Comment: Also, casts are only there to influence the "view" of the compiler. They do not actually "change" anything. Improper casting will result in `ClassCastException`s at runtime.

Comment: If you used an IDE and turned on the "Unnecessary cast" warning, you'd have gotten the answer, because the `(A)` cast would have generated warning like this: *"Unnecessary cast from B to A"* (quoted Eclipse warning)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no need for the cast there. In an [assignment context](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.2), a [widening reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5) is allowed. No need for a casting context. (Now, if it were a *narrowing* reference conversion, you'd have to do that explicitly.)

Answer (score 2):

The cast is redundant. `b2` gets assigned to `c` regardless, and invoking any methods on it will invoke the methods of `B` if they exist.